# How can I get the maximum date & it's total value for each week in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using the MongoDB shell to execute the query in the below query.

```
db.analytics.aggregate(
    [{ "$match": { "community": ObjectId("5e1ad5b6910a72a9bd02ccc8") } },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1, "date": 1, "week": { "$week": "$date" },
            "total": { "$add": ["$data.postCount", "$data.commentCount", "$data.voteCount.totalVotes", "$data.likeCount"] }
        }
    }])
```

Now I am getting it like in this below picture.

[image]

In the above picture, I have converted the date to week number, but now I need only the maximum date of each week total value only. How can I fix this?

Comment: Do u need max total of a week or max date of a week?

Comment: @saketh max date of a week  and that particular date total value

Comment: `$group` and its accumulator operator's `$max` should help you

Answer (score 0):

You can add these stages in your aggregation pipeline :

```
/** group on week & push max date to date field, plus push objects 0f {date, Total} to data field */
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$week",
    date: {
      "$max": "$date"
    },
    data: {
      $push: {
        date: "$date",
        Total: "$Total"
      }
    }
  }
},
/** Transform to needed fields & remove unnecessary fields,
 * Add a new Total field which will iterate on data array & get the object where data of that object
 *  matches with data field & use '$arrayElemAt' to get first object out of filtered array(anyway there will be only one object in array though)
 * So use '$let' to get total value out of object retrieved from '$arrayElemAt'
 */
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    week: "$_id",
    date: 1,
    Total: {
      $let: {
        vars: {
          total: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$data",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.date",
                      "$date"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        },
        in: "$$total.Total"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/y1eT65PNT8-)

Answer (score 0):

I am using this solutions, it's working fine.

```
db.analytics.aggregate({"$match":{"community":ObjectId("5e1ad5b6910a72a9bd02ccc8")}}, 
{"$sort":{"date":1}},
{"$project":{"_id":1, "date": 1, "week":{"$week":"$date"},
"total":{"$add":["$data.postCount", "$data.commentCount", "$data.voteCount.totalVotes", 
"$data.likeCount"]}}},
{"$group":{"_id":"$week","maxdate":{"$last":"$date"},"total":{"$last":"$total"}}},
{"$project":{"_id":"$_id","maxdate":1, "total":1}})
```

Comment: This would get you what you want but it necessarily might not work in all cases !! Cause if your application has an insertion order descending at any case then this query would yield incorrect responses, check in test portal, if that's not the case then this could work as days are added in ascending order !!